# Difference between tight and uniformly tight random variables?

Tags: probability, random-variable, measure-theory, sigma-algebra

[This wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tightness_of_measures) implicitly says that “tight” and “uniformly tight” random variables refers to the same concept.

I find this somewhat surprising. **Are there contexts in which a distinction is made between tightness and uniform tightness?** What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 4):

"Tight" describes a single random variable (or measure). "Uniformly tight" describes a collection of them which, for any epsilon, are all bounded by that epsilon outside of the same compact set.

In the context of random variables on the real numbers, tightness always holds true for a single random variable. So there is little reason to mention it until you're considering a collection, and then you're talking about uniform tightness. The distinction is there but not every author is careful to use the word "uniform".